# Is possible to remove the bottom links in a WP theme?

Tags: wordpress-theming, blogs

I am new to Wordpress, I am installing my first wp blog http://www.harobmxbikes.net/nanoc3/?p=1 , Is possible to remove the bottom links in a WP theme? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible as they are just HTML templates.

However, people have put time and effort into building these templates for you to use and it would be unethical to remove the links that credit their work.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the wp php file from FTP, modify the template, and re-upload again, by doing so, you can remove those links. :)